# Spring Boot Validation with spring-boot-starter-validation is not working for Spring boot version 2.4.4

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, validation

I was trying to validate a Request body in Spring boot and It's not working. Currently I'm using the Spring Boot 2.4.4 version. This is what I did.

I add this dependency `spring-boot-starter-validation`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The Controller with imported validation funcitons

```java
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/administration")
@Validated
public class AdminController {

    @PostMapping("/create-organization")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('all:write')")
    public ResponseEntity createNewOrganization(
            @Valid @RequestBody OrganizationDto organization) {

        Organization response = adminService.createNewOrganization(organization);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Location", "/api/organization/" + response.getId().toString());

        return new ResponseEntity(headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

OrganizationDto

```java
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotEmpty;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
public class OrganizationDto {

    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @NotBlank
    private String email;
}
```

The Problem I have is when I send the following body from Postman No error occurred.

```
{
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
}
```

Comment: Try adding @Validated also above the class OrganizationDto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Springboot

Removing **@RequestBody**, and simply leaving **@Valid** was enough to get it to work.

```
sendEmail(@Valid SMTPEmail emailToSend)
```

---

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Remove any hibernate-api and hibernate-validator dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems right and it should be working. So after that my advice would be:

1)Build the project with mvn clean install and try that jar that was built to see if it works

2)Or If you run it from Intelij

[image]

try to refresh maven dependencies and then run again

I suppose that you added later the dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and it was not correctly plugged in the dependencies.

Comment: Actually I have also added the `hibernate-validator` dependency and it cause the `spring-boot-starter-validation` validation to not work properly. Once I remove `hibernate-validator` everything works fine

Answer (score -3):

You should be using `@Validated` instead of `@Valid`

```
public ResponseEntity createNewOrganization(
            @Validated @RequestBody OrganizationDto organization) {
}
```